# Adjust top of div after load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently using the Intersoft Webgrid 9 for a bunch of our pages.  Some of the columns use the built in Calendar popup to edit the date.

The calendar is suppose to popup just under the textbox for editing.  In Chrome, this works fine but in IE the popup shows up quite a bit above the textbox.

The calendar popup is a div that is added to the page when the calendar image is first clicked.  After the initial click, the div remains on the page but either the visibility changes to hidden when no longer being used or the position changes based on the textbox being edited.

Since we are using Intersoft's resources, I do not have direct access to the javascript for the image click event.  I have however been able to add an additional click event to the calendar image but it fires before the div is drawn.  After that since the div is now on the page, I am able to adjust the top of the div with jquery through this click event.

So I guess if anyone knows of a way to adjust the calendar control through Intersoft's built in javascript that would be great.  Otherwise, I guess I was wondering if there was a way to adjust the top of the div after it has initially been added to the page.

I have attached two images.

Incorrectly displayed

[image]

Correctly displayed in Chrome

[image]

Thank you so much in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Is the text input element which the calendar is appended to relative or absolute positioned? If the calendar is being positioned absolutely then its parent needs to have relative positioning in order to work as expected. If you append an child with absolute positioning to an element with absolute positioning then they will both use the closest parent with relative positioning to calculate where they should be rendered.

Comment: You are right.  Both the calendar and textbox are absolute. Unfortunately there is absolutely nothing I can do about it. This is a third party control that has so many calculations to position the controls within in the grid, it's unreal and I cannot modify the source code.  That's why I wanted to see if there was a way to adjust the div after it had been added to the page for the first time.